# ggplot2 default blue and grey - what 'blue' and 'grey' are they specifically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating the default *Smoothed conditional means* plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

What is the default *blue* line color? What is the default *dark grey* background of the confidence intervals around the line? How did you figure this out?

I want to use these two exact colors for some of my other plots, to stay consistent.

Comment: what do you mean by default blue line color. Blue remains blue isn't it ? do you want hexadecimal code for these colors?

Comment: Exactly. Looks like the blue is `#3366FF` and the grey is `#999999`.

Comment: yeah then you can mention color = "#3366FF" in your ggplot(s) so your color remains consistent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ggplot_build` on a `ggplot` object to inspect its components. The `ggplot_built` object returned from this function includes a list called `data`, with the internal data used for building each geom. In this case, `geom_smooth` is the second geom, so it can be accessed with `ggplot_build(p)$data[[2]]`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

ggplot_build(p)$data[[2]] %>% head()
#>          x        y     ymin     ymax        se PANEL group  colour   fill
#> 1 1.600000 30.04871 29.17768 30.91974 0.4420916     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
#> 2 1.668354 29.80738 28.95779 30.65696 0.4312076     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
#> 3 1.736709 29.56605 28.73763 30.39446 0.4204623     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
#> 4 1.805063 29.32471 28.51718 30.13225 0.4098667     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
#> 5 1.873418 29.08338 28.29640 29.87036 0.3994326     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
#> 6 1.941772 28.84205 28.07529 29.60882 0.3891730     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
#>   size linetype weight alpha
#> 1    1        1      1   0.4
#> 2    1        1      1   0.4
#> 3    1        1      1   0.4
#> 4    1        1      1   0.4
#> 5    1        1      1   0.4
#> 6    1        1      1   0.4
```

As you can see, the defaults used to build the `geom_smooth` are a color of "#3366ff" and a fill of "grey60".

Here's a very lazy example of building a similar plot—obviously I'm not taking the time to calculate the actual standard error region, just making a thick gray line to illustrate the colors and alpha retrieved from the built plot.

```r
mod_coef <- lm(hwy ~ displ, mpg)$coefficients

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = mod_coef[1], slope = mod_coef[2], color = "grey60", alpha = 0.4, size = 6) +
  geom_abline(intercept = mod_coef[1], slope = mod_coef[2], color = "#3366FF", size = 1)
```

[image]